# Weird behavior with var in dict

Tags: python

```
>>> x = { 'a' : 'b' , 'c' : 'd' }

>>>'a' and 'c' in x
True

>>>'a' and 'b' in x
False

>>>'b' and 'c' in x
True
```

If `in <dict>` checks for keys, how come the last one that looks up `b` returns `true` even if there is no such key `b`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `'b' in x and 'c' in x`

You're misunderstanding how the `and` operator works (and you've got your operator precedence wrong).  `in` has a higher precedence than `and`, so your expression is parsed as:

```
if 'b' and ('c' in x):
```

which is the same as:

```
if 'c' in x:
```

because `bool('b')` is always `True` since `'b'` is a non-empty string.

Here is a [table of operator precedence in python](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary)

Note that even if `and` had higher precedence than `in`, you still wouldn't be getting what you want because `('b' and 'c') in x` would reduce down to `'c' in x` since `'b' and 'c'` returns `'c'`.

One way to rewrite your expression would be:

```
if all( key in yourdict for key in ('b', 'c') ):
```

This is overkill for just 2 keys to check, but quickly becomes useful if you have more keys to check.

As a final comment, you're probably trying to apply operator chaining (which is really neat).  However, some operators don't lend themselves to chaining very well (`in` is one of them).  Expressions like `3 > 10 > 100 > 1000` do work by some strange python black magic.  In my experience, relational operators chain nicely ('<','>','==','<=','>=') but most of the other operators don't chain in a way that is intuitive.  In general,

```
a operator b operator c operator ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
(a operator b) and (b operator c) and (c operator ...
```

Comment: No, `in` takes precedence over `and`, so it's `if 'b' and ('c' in x):` instead.

Comment: Explained well, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

This is equivalent to what you currently have:

```
>>> 'a' and ('c' in x)
True

>>> 'a' and ('b' in x)
False

>>> 'b' and ('c' in x)
True
```

You want this instead:

```
>>> 'a' in x and 'c' in x
True

>>> 'a' in x and 'b' in x
False

>>> 'b' in x and 'c' in x
False
```

Alternatively, you can use sets and the `<=` (subset) operator:

```
>>> set(['a', 'c']) <= set(x.keys())
True

>>> set(['a', 'b']) <= set(x.keys())
False

>>> set(['b', 'c']) <= set(x.keys())
False
```

In Python 2.7 and later, `set(['a', 'c'])` can be replaced with `{'a', 'b'}`.

Comment: FWIW -- I would think that `set( ('b','c') )` or even `set('bc')` would be faster than `set(['b','c'])`

Answer (score 0):

`'b'` is true, and `'c' in x` is also true. `(True and True) == True`. You need `'b' in x and 'c' in x`.

Answer (score 0):

`and` doesn't do what you think it's doing.

```
'a' and 'c' in x
```

means:

```
bool('a') and ('c' in x)
```

which means:

```
True and True
```

which means `True` of course :)

You need to do:

```
('a' in x) and ('c' in x)
```